# A word for a ship that's not sunk but stranded on a coast

Tags: word-request

A word for a ship that's not sunk but stranded on a coast. Let's say the hull of a ship got struck by a rock and there's a huge hole in the ship and the ship is stranded as a result. Is there a word to describe such ships? I recall there was one, but I can't remember what it was oddly enough.

Comment: There's "run aground" but that doesn't require the ship to be otherwise damaged.

Comment: Stricken perhaps. Or possibly 'holed,' 'left high and dry,' 'stuck fast.' I think only *people* get marooned.

Comment: Look up beached, foundered, hulk, and derelict.  "Shipwreck" is fine, as opposed to "sunken shipwreck"

Comment: Patrick O'Brian sometimes speaks of a ship having _struck upon a rock_ (or a reef).